# Error occurred while checking for updates.Unable to establish connection with R session Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I am unable to load an R project and I am getting an error: `Error occurred while checking for updates. Unable to establish a connection with R session with R studio.` I am using large data sets inside that projects which might be causing this issue. Is there a way I could log in from the terminal and remove some datasets from the workspace. Can someone help how I can log in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're auto-saving the workspace to `.RData`. It's usually not a problem (though still not advised) to do so with small-ish data sets/objects in the workspace but it's almost deadly to use this setting if you work with large data sets/objects often.

Disable the `Restore .RData into workspace at startup` setting in RStudio preferences and also set `Save workspace to .RData on exit` to `Never`.

Hunt down all the `.RData` files in your various working directories and delete them, too.

Comment: I am saving to .RProj file and i am not able to open it as i didn't clear the workspace. I know the files which must be causing this error but i cannot login so i am unable to clear. Any advise how i can clear the workspace?

Comment: There has to be an `.RData` file in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. And the above proposed strategy did not work well. However, having anaconda installed in my PC I downloaded Rstudio on that platform. Contrarily to the other Rstudio standalone version, Rstudio in anaconda works well. I do not know why, but in case of need you can smash out your Rstudio without deleting your files and use the Rstudio on the anaconda platform. Just to have another point of view!